# How to add build inside nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-attributes, simple-form-for

I don't know how to ask this. How I can do this in my nested form. When I clicked new. I want to populate some field of my customer_answer_detail from customer_template_detail. I have for loop inside nested form but `@customer_answer.customer_answer_details.build` is not working inside.

**code:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer_answer do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :customer_answer_details, :wrapper => false do |p| %>
        <% @customer_template.customer_template_details.each do |ctd| %>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= p.input :name, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => ctd.name } %>
                <%= p.input :customer_template_detail_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => ctd.id } %>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><%= ctd.name %></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <%= p.input :answer,
                        :label => false,
                        :input_html => {:class => "form-control"} %>
                </div><!-- /form col-sm-10-->  
            </div><!-- /form group-->

            <% @customer_answer.customer_answer_details.build %>

        <% end %>  
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Do you have idea how to do this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish. Can you describe your problem from a business requirements perspective rather than showing this code... as the code you're showing seems unusual (to put it politely)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, just doing it in the wrong sequence.

Right now, you're rendering the form before building any `@customer_answer.customer_answer_details`.

Shift the `@customer_answer.customer_answer_details.build` into your `new` controller action (and `create` if there is a chance of `create` failing and rendering `new`).

Comment: I'm thinking to do it in controller. For example in new. i will just add `@customer_answer.customer_answer_details.build` but after that what is the next step to populate that details can I, after `build` `@customer_answer.customer_answer_details.name = "sample text"` ?

Comment: I got it. Thanks. What I did is put the`for loop` in action new and `@customer_answer.customer_answer_details.build(:name => "test")` inside the loop.

Comment: @do_Ob: What do you need the `for` loop for?